# Laravel 10 to Microsoft SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, vue.js, laravel-10

I'm trying to connect my Laravel 10 Project on Microsoft SQL Server and everytime i do php artisan migrate it always says Nothing to Migrate or this error right here.

> " Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP
> Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine
> actively refused it.  (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select * from
> sys.sysobjects where id = object_id(migrations) and xtype in ('U',
> 'V'))"

I already changed my
DB CONNECTION
DB_HOST
DB_PORT
DB_DATABASE
DB_USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD

I already tried installing Php sql server driver, and configure the config.ini on my xamp.

Comment: if it says ```nothing to migrate``` you can try to run ```php artisan migrate:reset```. And about those error, have you check your firewall ?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server Express edition... what you are putting in DB port? A lot of versions of Express don't even listen on a TCP port by default (although they can be configured to) and of those that do, they're listening on a random port that needs to be determined using the `SQLExpress` instance name by way of the SQL Browser service, e.g.: `Server=.\SQLExpress;`, `Server=localhost\SQLExpress;` or `Server=127.0.0.1\SQLExpress;`.

Comment: How is `vue.js` related?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the port number at the configuration if you are at a local enviroment. It's normal at SQLExpress that hasn't got the port asignament
Make sure your Firewall has the rules for the port and enable the TCP/IP Conections at the SQL configuration manager.